# SVG funciri and System.Uri

Tags: .net, svg, uri

I am using the .NET [svg rendering engine](http://svg.codeplex.com) to convert an svg file to png.

Everything is working as expected except for one detail. The clippaths.
I have to manually link the clippath defined in the definitionlist and the element that needs a clipPath.

**the ClipPath property of an SVGElement has the System.URI type. But all I have is a functional uri notation from the svg like this => url(#myId)**

How do I make up the System.Uri object?

Comment: Long shot, but if you are having trouble with this library, you can render svg to png very easily using the `inkscape` binary, which runs fine on the Windows platform.

Comment: It seemed I had an old version of the library which did not support Clipping. I am not using inkscape or batik because of monitoring issues.

Comment: Cool, if you've fixed it, pop the answer below - and give yourself a tick `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an old version of the library, in the new version the clipping works as it should.

more info can be found [here](http://svg.codeplex.com/discussions/349300)